# Perl Getopt::Long - use subparameter only for defined parameter

Tags: perl, getopt-long

I would like the --import parameter to have a "sub-parameter" that will only work on this parameter, nowhere else. Example:

```
app.pl --import --fresh
```

output: command working

```
app.pl --export
```

output: command working

```
app.pl --export --fresh
```

output: command not found

Can this be achieved by GetOpt::Long? Please, guide me a little.

Comment: If `--fresh` feeds the `$fresh` variable, and `--import` and `--export` feed the `$import` and `$export` variables, you can always just `die "--fresh only valid with --import or --export\n" if $fresh && ! $import;` as the next line after `GetOptions()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that without resorting to partial parsing the closest you can get to with Getopt::Long is this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Getopt::Long;

GetOptions('export=s%{1,5}'=>\my %export, 'another_option=s'=>\my $ao);

print Dumper({ 'export'=> \%export, 'another_option'=>$ao});
```

---

```
perl t1.pl  --export fresh=1 b=2 c=3 --another_option value
```

---

```
$VAR1 = {
          'export' => {
                        'c' => '3',
                        'b' => '2',
                        'fresh' => '1'
                      },
          'another_option' => 'value'
        };
```

Here `export=s%{1,5}` parses `--export fresh=1 b=2 c=3` into hash `%export`.
`s%{1,5}` expects from 1 to 5 `key=value` pairs

Answer (score 2):

Options can indeed require a parameter. The parameter doesn't use `--`, though.

```
GetOptions(
   'help'     => \&help,
   'import:s' => \$opt_import,
)
   or usage();

defined($opt_import) && ( $opt_import eq '' || opt_import eq 'fresh' )
   or usage("Invalid value for --import");

@ARGV == 0
   or usage("Incorrect number of arguments");

# Convert into booleans for convenience.
$opt_fresh = defined($opt_import) && $opt_import eq 'fresh';
$opt_import = defined($opt_import);
```

The above accepts the following:

```
app.pl --import fresh
app.pl --import
app.pl
```

Note that using `=s` instead of `:s` will make providing a value mandatory.

---

Sample helpers:

```
use FIle::Basename qw( basename );

sub usage {
   my $basename = basename($0);
   print("usage: $basename [options]\n");
   print("       $basename --help\n");
   print("\n");
   print("Options:\n");
   print("\n");
   print("   --import [fresh]\n");
   exit(0);
}

sub usage {
   if (@_) {
      chomp( my $msg = shift );
      warn("$msg\n");
   }

   my $basename = basename($0);
   warn("Try '$basename --help' for more information.\n);
   exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I take the purpose for this invocation, that matters for implementation here, to be the following.

There is a flag (call it `$fresh`) that need be set under the `--import` option, along with other flag(s) associated with `--import`.  Additionally, there may be an independent option `--fresh`, which sets the `$fresh` flag.

While [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) doesn't support nested options this can be achieved using its other facilities. Set `--import` to take an optional argument with `:`, and set variables [in a sub](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#User-defined-subroutines-to-handle-options). If the word `fresh` is submitted as the value set the corresponding (`$fresh`) flag.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Getopt::Long;

my ($import, $fresh); 

GetOptions( 
    'import:s' => sub { 
        $import = 1;  
        $fresh  = 1 if $_[1] eq 'fresh';
    },
    'fresh!' => \$fresh   # if independent --fresh option is needed
);

say 'import: ', $import // 'not submitted';   #/
say 'fresh:  ', $fresh  // 'not submitted';
```

The sub receives two arguments, the option name and value, and the value is used to check whether `fresh` was passed. The code as it stands does nothing for other words that may be passed, but it can be made to abort (with a usage message) if any value other than `fresh` is submitted.

Whatever particular reasons there are to require this invocation can be coded in the sub.

If a separate `--fresh` option is indeed provided then the user need be careful since it is possible to submit conflicting values for `$fresh` – one with `--import` and another in `--fresh` itself. This can be checked for in the code.

The option `--import` still works as a simple flag on its own.

Valid invocations are

```
gol.pl --import         # $import is 1
gol.pl --import fresh   # $import is 1, $fresh is 1
gol.pl --fresh          # $fresh is 1
```

Since `fresh` is set in a sub as a value of `--import` it cannot be set with any other options.

This differs from the requirement by having `fresh` as a word, without dashes.